# Prove electric and magnetic waves are perpendicular

Tags: physics, vectors

So I have $2$ electric waves and $2$ magnetic waves, and I need to prove mathematically that the total electric and total magnetic waves are perpendicular. $E_1$ is in the $x$-direction and $E_2$ is in the $y$-direction. $B_1$ is in the $y$-direction and $B_2$ is in the $-x$-direction. The two waves are are cosines but have different phases - represented by $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$:

\begin{align*}
E_1 &= x (E)\cos(kz-wt-\phi_1)\\
E_2 &= y (E)\cos(kz-wt-\phi_2)\\
B_1 &= y (B)\cos(kz-wt-\phi_1)\\
B_2 &= -x(B)\cos(kz-wt-\phi_2)
\end{align*}

The letters in front indicate the unit vector direction.

Total $E$ field is $E_t = E_1+E_2$, total magnetic field is $B_t = B_1+B_2$.

I need to show that $E_t$ and $B_t$ are perpendicular. I think to do this I need to show that their dot product is zero, but how do I take the dot product of $E_t$ and $B$?

Comment: I am guessing that you have the phase shifts mixed up above. As is, the two vectors are not necessarily orthogonal.

Comment: nope I don't think so. Check out the question - part C at http://cl.ly/image/2y1T0U1w3k0Q

Comment: And conceptually they have to be orthogonal since that is a natural property of electromagnetic waves

Comment: Hmm, your transcription of the problem is very misleading.

Comment: In the question, they use $\hat{x}, \hat{y}$ to denote unit vectors in the $x,y$ directions respectively. You have omitted the $E_0,B_0$ from the original problem. I have updated my answer to address Part (c) of the problem you have shown in your comment above.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: This answer is based on the actual problem as provided in a comment by the OP above.

To simplify notation, let $c_1(z,t) = \cos(kz-wt-\phi_1), c_2(z,t) = \cos(kz-wt-\phi_2)$.

The $E$ field is given by $E_0(c_1(z,t), c_2(z,t))$, or, 
$E_0c_1(z,t)i + E_0 c_2(z,t)) j$.

The $B$ field is given by $B_0(-c_2(z,t), c_1(z,t))$, or, 
$-B_0 c_2(z,t)i + B_0 c_1(z,t)) j$.

The dot or inner product is given by $E \cdot B = E_0 B_0 c_1(z,t) c_2(z,t) + E_0 B_0 (-c_2(z,t)) c_1(z,t) = 0$.

Comment: Dear copper.hat, The statement of the question is a bit hard to parse, but I think that $E = E_1 i + E_2 j,$ while $B = - B_2 i + B_1 j$.  (Here $E_i$ and $B_i$ are the phase-shifted cosines; the OP seems to say that the expressions $x(E)$ etc. simply indicate unit vectors along the relevenat axis, so $x(E)$ just means $i$, while $y(B)$ means $j$, etc.)  If my interpretation is correct, then the dot product will be zero.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE: Yes, I think you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have your definition wrong.  The total electric field is the vector whose components are given by $E_1$ and $E_2$.  Similarly, the total magnetic field is the vector whose components are $B_1$ and $B_2$.  So, the dot product will simply be
$$
E \cdot B = \langle E_1,E_2 \rangle \cdot \langle B_1, B_2 \rangle =
E_1 B_1 + E_2 B_2
$$
**Edit:** sorry, I misunderstood. You said that your $B_1$ is in the $y$ direction and your $B_2$ is in the "$-x$" direction.  That would give you
$$
E \cdot B = \langle E_1,E_2 \rangle \cdot \langle -B_2,B_1 \rangle =
-E_1 B_2 + E_2 B_1=E_2B_1 - E_1B_2
$$
$E_1,E_2,B_1,$ and $B_2$ are *scalar* quantities, which is why we can multiply them.  You cannot multiply vectors; you can only take the dot-product (or cross-product) of the which is not the same thing.  From this point, you'll have to go through the math to show that $E_2B_1 - E_1B_2 = 0$ for any value of $t$.

Comment: so since E_1 and B_1 are in different directions you get zero when you multiply them? And same for E_2 B_2? So no calculations are even necessary?

Comment: See my latest edit.  I seem to have misunderstood your original phrasing.